# AEM Venia Store Category and Product Page data Not fetching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, adobe, aem-6

Basically, I have set up a default AEM 6.5 venia theme with no customizing, I also successfully connected the CIF connector and fetched data from Magento using CIF Connector, but when I tried to the category as well as product page the data of product is not fetching at all, In commerce option, I can see all data fetching from Magento side.

I found that in search the data and layered navigation is working fine, but when coming to the category and list page the issue coming up with no data. I found out there is an error on the console hereby attach the screenshot for reference.

```
Could not fetch storefront instance context Error: Cannot query field "dataServicesStorefrontInstanceContext" on type "Query"
```

I Found that before the DOM page is loaded the React part is loading
Attaching the screenshots for reference.

[image]

**App.Js**

```
window.onload = () => {
    const root = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(root);
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>,
        root
    );
};
```

Comment: Replied to the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69151701/673984