# Getting error with Venia code after integrated Magento with AEM as a Cloud Service SDK with the CIF Add-On installed

Tags: javascript, magento, sdk, aem

We are using AEM as a Cloud Service SDK with the CIF Add-On to connect with Magento. After deployed Venia code we are not able to see the category and product images and seeing this error in console:

[image: error]

`Could not fetch storefront instance context Error: Cannot query field "dataServicesStorefrontInstanceContext" on type" Query"`.
We are able to see the products on the commerce page (http://localhost:4502/aem/products.html/var/commerce/products) as the configuration in cloud service is done properly.

Getting below error in error.log file:

```
GET /content/venia/us/en.html HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.cq.commerce.graphql.client.impl.GraphqlClientImpl GraphQL request {categoryList(filters:{category_uid:{eq:"52"}}){uid,name,url_path,position,children{uid,name,url_path,position,children{uid,name,url_path,position}}}} returned some errors [{"message":"Field \"category_uid\" is not defined by type CategoryFilterInput.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":24}]},{"message":"Cannot query field \"uid\" on type \"CategoryTree\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":49}]},{"message":"Cannot query field \"uid\" on type \"CategoryTree\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":85}]},{"message":"Cannot query field \"uid\" on type \"CategoryTree\".","locations":[{"line":1,"column":121}]}]
```

Kindly suggest if there are any references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have referred the Venia Project. Please find the  [code](https://github.com/adobe/aem-cif-guides-venia) here

Answer (score 1):

This error shows up if you do not have `magento/module-data-services-graphql` module installed on the Commerce side as documented [here](https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/product-recs/#install-the-product-recommendations-module) (Step 3). Once you install that and check back in AEM, that error should go away. That feature is required for the "Product Recommendations" feature in Adobe Commerce.